# How to get value of a FormControl in Angular4

Tags: angular

I have some experience in Angular4, but I just inherited a piece of code that uses FormControls, and I don't know how to work with them.  I am setting up a comments textarea that is required if the value of isRegulatoryAuditRequired equals false.  I've got the required field working, but I need to display the message 'Comments required' if value is false and the form is submitted.  Here is my HTML, with two radio buttons, a textarea and a label for the message:

```html
<div class="btnWrapper">
  <div class="leftBtn">
    <span class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" class="app-input-radio" name="isRegulatoryAuditRequired" [value]="true"
               [checked]="isRegulatoryAuditRequired==true" formControlName="isRegulatoryAuditRequired" />
        <span class="app-input-radio pull-left"></span>
        <span class="plx5 pull-left radioText ">Yes</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="rightBtn">
    <span class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" class="app-input-radio" name="isRegulatoryAuditRequired" [value]="false"
               [checked]="isRegulatoryAuditRequired==false" formControlName="isRegulatoryAuditRequired" />
        <span class="app-input-radio pull-left"></span>
        <span class="plx5 pull-left radioText ">No</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mbx20">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div>
      <label>Why is the regulatory audit being performed or provide additional comment?</label>
      <div>
        <textarea id="comments" name="Text1" [required]="isRegulatoryAuditRequired==false" cols="100" rows="2" formControlName="comments"></textarea>
        <label *ngIf="commentsRequired('comments')" style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Comments required</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to evaluate the value of the 'isRegulatoryAuditRequired' and 'comments' FormControls to see if I should display the 'Comments required' message.  Here is the method I'm trying to use, but it isn't working:

```ts
commentsRequired(controlName: string) {
  const control = (<FormControl>this.rotationForm.controls[controlName]);
  const isRegulatoryAuditRequired = (<FormControl>this.rotationForm.controls['isRegulatoryAuditRequired']);
  if (isRegulatoryAuditRequired.value === false && control.value === '' && this.formSubmitAttempt) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The value of 'isRegulatoryAuditRequired.value' and 'control.value' print to the console as null, which therefore doesn't display the message.  How do I retrieve these values?  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you define somewhere in your template `<div [formGroup]="rotationForm">Form content here</div>` ?

Comment: Yes <form [formGroup]="rotationForm" (ngSubmit)="save(rotationForm.value,rotationForm.valid)" novalidate>

Answer (score 78, accepted):

you can do `this.rotationForm.get('comments').value` this will give you the value of the formControl and then you can check on the length.

doing this `this.rotationForm.value.comments` will work too **BUT NOT** for ***disabled*** fields, to get the value of the ***DISABLED*** fields use the `this.rotationForm.get('comments').value`

Comment: Thank you!  Trying to retrieve those values was giving me fits!

Answer (score 1):

Having validation at the FormGroup level in the component

```
this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
  'email': new FormControl('example@example.com', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
  ])),
```

I was able to pluck the email value like this in my function:

email = this.loginForm.value.email

Worked for me - hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get in this two ways:

```
this.yourFormName.get('yourFormControlName').value
this.yourFormName.controls['yourFormControlName'].value
```